# Write a function that takes in no arguments and returns two functions, prepend and get,

Tags: python, python-nonlocal

Write a function that takes in no arguments and returns two functions, prepend and
get, which represent the “add to front of list” and “get the ith item” operations,
respectively. Do not use any python built-in data structures like lists or dictionaries.
You do not necessarily need to use all the lines

```
def nonlocalist():
    get = lambda x: "Index out of range!"
    def prepend(value):
        nonlocal get
        f = get
        def get(i):
            if i == 0:
                return value
            return f(i - 1)
    return prepend, lambda x: get(x)
```

can someone help explain how these codes work, i have no idea from the beginning how to write it.

Comment: How should *"Do not use any python built-in data structures like lists"* and *"add to front of list"* fit together?

Comment: I don't know either. That's a question from UCB CS61's discussion question, very tough.

Comment: @Klaus Using closures as data storage and recursion to retrieve them…

Comment: The call stack is essentially acting as your list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell, this works by storing data in closures, and using recursion to retrieve them. As a very short primer on closures:

```
def foo(value):
    def bar():
        print(value)

    return bar

b = foo(42)
b()  # prints 42
```

The `value` here is being "closed over". This means even though the execution of `foo` has already ended and the variable `value` *should* have gone out of scope and been garbage collected, since `bar` refers to it, it is still kept around and is in fact accessible to `bar` when called.

Your linked list code uses this principle to store values in more and more nested scopes, and uses recursion to traverse back up the scopes and retrieve them.

Here's a visualisation of this abomination in action:

[image: Pythontutor visualisation]

You can play around with it yourself [here](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#code=def%20nonlocalist%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20get%20%3D%20lambda%20x%3A%20%22Index%20out%20of%20range!%22%0A%20%20%20%20def%20prepend%28value%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20nonlocal%20get%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20f%20%3D%20get%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20def%20get%28i%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20i%20%3D%3D%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20value%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20f%28i%20-%201%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20prepend,%20lambda%20x%3A%20get%28x%29%0A%0Ap,%20g%20%3D%20nonlocalist%28%29%0Ap%2842%29%0Ap%28%27foo%27%29%0Ag%281%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=26&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false).

---

When calling `nonlocalist`, you get two functions back: `prepend`, and a function that calls the "latest version" of `get`.

`prepend` always does the same thing:

1. Take a `value` argument.
2. Store the current version of `get` in `f`.
3. Overwrite `get` with a new function which either:

   - returns `value` (as demonstrated in the closure example above), or
   - calls the previous version of `get` (now called `f`), which has the previous `value` closed over

When you call the second "getter" function that `nonlocalist` gave you, it:

1. Looks up the current version of `get` and calls it, which
2. returns the `value` it has closed over or the result of its previous version.

Comment: do you know why `return prepend, get` generates a different output than `return prepend, lambda x: get(x)`? Essentially, why should `get` need an extra wrap?

Comment: That’s why I emphasized that the returned function *looks up the current `get`.* The specific function that the name `get` refers to changes, so it matters whether you return the first `get` function object, or a function that looks up the name `get` when called.